# How to change ${USER} value in WebStorm or PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How to change `${USER}` value in JetBrains WebStorm?

I was searching under `Settings-> File and Code Templates` but there I can change only structure of the temple instead of value of variable `USER`.

```
/**
* Created by ${PRODUCT_NAME}.
* User: ${USER}
* Date: ${DATE}
* Time: ${TIME}
* To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
*/
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Goto  Settings-> File and Code Templates

choose desired file type and use set command.

```
  #set( $USER = "your desired name" )
```

For example: For Javascript

```
/**
 * #set( $USER = "your desired name" )
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

Answer (score 15):

By default `${USER}` variable value is your login name as returned by java `System.getProperty('user.name')`. 
You can override it by passing a different name to java via `-Duser.name` option that you need to add to `.vmoptions` file: choose **Help | Edit Custom VM Options...**, add `-Duser.name=your desired name` to it

Comment: Preferred solution !

Comment: Restart PHPStorm to apply changes to custom VM Options.
File location: .config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.2/phpstorm64.vmoptions